# Register composed structs with luabridge

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I've the following `GlobalStruct` struct that I want to parse from a lua table:

```cpp
namespace N1 {
struct DetailedStruct {
  int i1;
  int i2;
};
}

namespace N2 {
struct GlobalStruct {
  int i1;
  N1::DetailedStruct ds1;
}
}
```

With [luabridge3](https://github.com/kunitoki/LuaBridge3) how can I register the `DetailedStruct` attribute?

```cpp
luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
  .beginClass<N2::GlobalStruct >("N2_GlobalStruct ")
  .addConstructor<void (*) (void)>()
  .addProperty("i1", &N2::GlobalStruct::i1)
  // register ds1 attribute?
  .endClass();
```

I can use `.addProperty` for registering `i1` attribute, but I don't know how to add `ds1` property that's of type `N1::DetailedStruct` (another struct in another namespace).

What should I do?